# Fade on hover with CSS3

Tags: animation, css, fade

Can anyone let me know why my element will not fade in?

The background image properly animates, but the .home class just appears rather than fading in?

Thanks, code snippet is below.

```
#home {
                                width:35px;
                                height:35px;
                                float:left;
                                margin:20px 20px 0 20px;
                                transition:background-position .2s ease;
                                -webkit-transition: background-position .2s ease;
                                -moz-transition: background-position .2s ease;
                                background-image:url('images/icons.png');
                        }
#home > .home {
                                position:absolute;
                                display:none;
                                margin-top:40px;
                                opacity:0;
                                transition:opacity 3s linear;
                        }
                        #home:hover > .home {
                                display:block;
                                opacity:1;
                        }
                        #home:hover {
                                background-position:0px 35px;
                        }

<!-- END STYLE START HTML -->
<div id="home"><div class="home">HOME</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transition on hover as well.

```
#home:hover > .home {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 3s linear;
}
```

For cross-browsing transition add:

```
-moz-transition ...
-webkit-transition ...
-o-transition ...
```

-ms- is not supported.

Answer (score -2):

From W3Schools: "The transition property is not supported in any browsers.". Instead, use the specific transition properties for Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp

IE does not support this at all.

If you want real working transitions, you should consider using a javascript library that supports animations like JQuery.

Comment: It cleary states on W3Schools: "Internet Explorer does not yet support the transition property." and also that "The transition property is not supported in any browsers.". Please do your research before voting down.

Comment: [W3Schools is not a good source](http://w3fools.com/), try [doing some more research yourself](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Comment: IE 10 has not even been released yet, so the statements above are very much true. Also, building applications and features that are supported by just one version of a specific (and widely used) browser is an extremely bad practice. Your half-witted statement is completely pointless in this context.